# Report Manager insufficient permission error

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I have had a user with browser role which has been able to make subscriptions but he has not seen CC and BCC fields. Because of that, I added Content Manager role for him to all folders and reports and after that, he cannot make more subscriptions or manage reports in any way. He gets error
"The permissions granted to user 'domain\username' are insufficient for performing this operation". Now he can only see the reports.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Browse to Site Settings, Configure item level role definitions.
Then check what settings you have for Content Manager. Maybe someone removed them.

[image]

Comment: Hope you don't mind my asking, but I've never be aware that one could control which tasks are available to a role? When I go into Site Settings, I just see the three familiar options (General, Security and Schedules) plus the new Branding option on 2016.

Comment: Sorry. I'm on 2005 still. I assume 2016 is a big difference.

Comment: That's OK. I've found it now. Not accessible through the portal anymore by the looks of it. Instead connect to Reporting Services via SSMS and they're on the Security node. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

When I added a role also to the Home folder then it starts working. I don't know why, before this was not needed.